# How to calculate box width and height form css properties(top, bottom, left, right) using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have top, bottom, left, right position of a box drawn on a canvas using mouse. How can i calculate the width and height of that box

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: use get client rect https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` method which returns the **size** of an element and its **position** relative to the viewport.

This method returns a **DOMRect** object with eight properties: **left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height**.

[Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for more info.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = rect.left;
  y = rect.top;
  w = rect.width;
  h = rect.height;
  console.log("Left: " , x , ", Top: " , y , ", Width: " , w , ", Height: " , h);
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="240" height="297">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```